# Pass method to method as an argument in Java

Tags: java

I want to pass a method to a method as an argument and I want to develop a system as follows.

How can I develop it in java?

Pseudo code:

```
class A
{
    public void test(Method method, Method method2)
    {
        if(Condition)
        {
            method.run();
        }
        else
        {
            method2.run();
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    A a = new A();
    a.test(foo(),bar());

    public void foo()
    {
        print "hello";
    }
    public void bar()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't pass a method. You pass an object of a class implementing an interface. In your case, the existing `Runnable` interface will fit nicely, since it has a single `run` method with no input arguments and no return value.

```
class A
{
    public void test(Runnable method, Runnable method2)
    {
        if(Condition)
        {
            method.run();
        }
        else
        {
            method2.run();
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("hello1");
            }
        };
        Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("hello2");
            }
        };
        a.test(r1,r2);
    }
}
```

If you are using Java 8, you can simplify the syntax with lambda expressions :

```
class B
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.test(() -> System.out.println("hello1"),() -> System.out.println("hello2"));
    }
}
```

Or you can use method references (again, only in Java 8), which the compiler can match to the functional interface expected by the `test()` method :

```
class B
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.test(B::foo,B::bar); // though foo() and bar() must be static in this case,
                               // or they wouldn't match the signature of the run()
                               // method of the Runnable interface expected by test()
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you figure out that `Runnable` is an issue here? It's just pseudo code

Comment: @ceran Runnable is a functional interface with a single method having no input parameters and no return value. Therefore it perfectly fits the example in the question.

Comment: @Eran Sure, there's no doubt about that. I just wondered about _"In your case, Runnable will do, since it has the method run"_ but I got it now :)

Comment: @Chris Fixed now. I forgot the `void` keyword in the `run()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your scenario and the version of Java you are using.

Using so called *single abstract method interfaces* or *functional interfaces* with [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) is a common pattern in Java. You are basically implementing an anonymous class via an interface and pass the resulting object to your methods. This works for all versions of Java.

```
// CheckPerson is the interface to implement
fetchPersons(
    new CheckPerson() {
        public boolean test(Person p) {
            return p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
                && p.getAge() >= 18
                && p.getAge() <= 25;
        }
    }
);
```

---

Java 8 recreates that concept and provides [Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) which makes things more elegant and functional.

```
fetchPersons(
    (Person p) -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
        && p.getAge() >= 18
        && p.getAge() <= 25
);
```

---

Apart from the solutions above, you might be interested in the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: Can you please update your reply with complete codes?

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface with that method signature, and pass an anonymous subclass of it with your method implementation.

create an interface like containing the method u want to pass as argument :

```
 public interface methodInterface{

   method(parameter here);


}
```

Then implement it in a class

Then create implementations for each of your range checking methods:

```
    public class class1 implements methodInterface{

    public method(//parameters here) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Then your other method's signature becomes:

```
public void enterUserInput(methodInterface method)
```