# Lambda as method with arguments and primitives in Java

Tags: java, lambda, primitive-types

I have a class making operations on a chess board. Every cell has its states. The board is an array whose declaration is:

```
private CellState[][] cellBoard = new CellState[8][8];
```

I have many methods that have 3 arguments: row (horizontal), file (vertical) and state. They traverse board cell by cell. To refactor repeating code, I wrote the following method:

```
private void traverseBoard(Command method) {
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        for(int file = 0; file < 8; file++) {
            method.execute(row, file, cellBoard[row][file]);
        }
    }
}

protected interface Command {
    public void execute(int x, int y, CELL_STATE state);
}
```

In one of the methods, I check if every cell is empty:

```
private boolean areAllEmpty() {
    ExtendedBoolean empty = new ExtendedBoolean(true);
    traverseBoard((i, j, state) -> {
        if (state != CELL_STATE.EMPTY) {
            empty.set(false);
        }
    });
    return empty.is();
}
```

I could not use the primitive `boolean`, because it is immutable. For that purpose, I created a nested class:

```
private class ExtendedBoolean {
    boolean bool;

    public ExtendedBoolean(boolean bool) {
        this.bool = bool;
    }

    public void set(boolean bool) {
        this.bool = bool;
    }

    public boolean is() {
        return bool;
    }
}
```

I hope there is a better way of passing a method with multiple arguments inside a lambda expression. I am aware it is possible to use `Runnable` [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26312605/7769052). However, in that case I cannot pass any parameter.

I hope that I don't have to write `ExtendedBoolean`, whose only purpose is to wrap a primitive. I had to write `ExtendedInteger` as well.

Are my hopes reasonable?

**EDIT:** The collection of cell states has to be mutable. I change states of cells and then check them. I do it in a loop until condition is fulfilled.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel with ExtendedBoolean and ExtendedInteger. Java already has wrappers for primitives, Boolean and Integer to name the ones you're using.

Comment: Eh.  There are a couple approaches to this problem, but I wouldn't call any of the ones using lambdas nice.  Lambdas aren't really good at maintaining state.

Comment: The difference between your `ExtendedBoolean` and an ordinary `Boolean` is that it is **Mutable**. There are mutables that you can use instead (such as `AtomicBoolean`) but most have unnecessary side-effects.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Java [naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2697/oracle-official-code-standard/9031/naming-conventions#t=201706261657484606575) is for class names to be mixed case, with leading uppercase letter, so `CELL_STATE` is badly named, and should be `CellState` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I oversaw it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Stream to represent your board, and thus benefit of all the Stream methods:

```
    Stream<Cell> stream =
        IntStream.range(0, 64)
            .mapToObj(i -> {
                int row = i / 8;
                int column = i % 8;
                return new Cell(row, column, cellBoard[row][column]);
            });
```

where the Cell class would be defined as

```
private static class Cell {
    private final int row;
    private final int column;
    private final CELL_STATE state;

    public Cell(int row, int column, CELL_STATE state) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    public CELL_STATE getState() {
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cell{" +
            "row=" + row +
            ", column=" + column +
            ", state=" + state +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Now, to implement your usecase, all you would have to do would be

```
stream.allMatch(cell -> cell.getState() == CELL_STATE.EMPTY);
```

Comment: I like your code very much. It surely simplifies my `areAllEmpty` method. The problem is that streams are immutable, but I have to change the states of cells many times.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to combine generics and lambdas together with something like this:

```
protected interface Command<T> {
    public T execute(T prev, int x, int y, CELL_STATE state);
}


private <T> T traverseBoard(T initial, Command<T> method) {
    T result = initial;
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        for(int file = 0; file < 8; file++) {
            result = method.execute( result, row, file, null );
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private boolean areAllEmpty() {
    return traverseBoard( Boolean.FALSE, (b, i, j, state) -> {
        if ( state != CELL_STATE.EMPTY ) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    } );
}

private int count() {
    return traverseBoard( 0, (c, i, j, state) -> c += 1 );
}
```

I also throw in an example of how you can do count in order to see how state is maintained.

But I like @JB Nizet answer using streams.

Comment: The drawback is that I have to return, even if I change cell states. I would have to write 2 methods: `traverseBoardChangingStates` and `traverseBoardCheckingStates`.

Comment: Just return `null` if you dont need the value.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to write your own simple generic Mutable:

```
public class Mutable<T> {
    T it;

    public Mutable(T it) {
        this.it = it;
    }

    public void set(T it) {
        this.it = it;
    }

    public T get() {
        return it;
    }
}
```

You can then use a `Mutable<Boolean>` in your case and rely on autoboxing to make it handle `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

In lambdas all variables that are captured from the outside scope (clojure) need to be final, or effectively final, and thats why it does not let you directly change a variable, if Javas Implementation for clojures were like those of C# or JavaScript you would not need to use this.

A pattern used in Java is to declare an array with only 1 element in this case array with one boolean and then change the content of the array (i think it is ugly).

```
boolean[] empty = new boolean[]{false};
traverseBoard((i,j,state) -> empty[0] = true ) // Simple usage
```

I think this solution (my opinion) is ugly, another one is to create an Holder class, that is Generic, so whenever you need something similar you could used it.

As an example:

`Holder<Student> studentHolder = new Holder<>(student);
 doSomething( anotherStudent -> studentHolder.value = anotherStudent );`

With this last approach be sure to create default ones for primitive types, so there is no Boxing/Unboxing overhead.

```
BooleanHolder boolHolder = new BooleanHolder(false);
```

Comment: I also think approach with an array is too ugly. I don't see any improvement with `BooleanHolder` in comparison to my `ExtendedBoolean`, except of generic property. @OldCurmudgeon's comment is more clear for me, though.

Comment: I think you should remain with the generic and for primitive types implement their own version, this way you remove the cost of boxing and unboxing, if you take a look at Java Functional Interfaces they did that for every primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

Your `traverseBoard` method is correct if all you want to do is take some action for each cell. However, if you need to check some condition on each cell, you need another approach.

As I see it, the problem is that you need to design a method that traverses your board and returns a `boolean` instead of `void`. Here's something to start with:

```
private boolean allCellsInBoardMatch(Condition condition) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        for (int file = 0; file < 8; file++) {
            if (!condition.check(row, file, cellBoard[row][file])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

protected interface Condition {
    boolean check(int x, int y, CELL_STATE state);
}
```

This approach, besides working as expected without needing a wrapper type, is more efficient, because it stops iterating as soon as the condition is not met for a cell, while the approach you were using was traversing the whole board.

Your example that checks if all the cells are empty could now be rewritten as follows:

```
private boolean areAllEmpty() {
    return allCellsInBoardMatch((i, j, state) -> state == CELL_STATE.EMPTY);
}
```